# INSERT INTO two tables usnig select guid

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert, guid

Using Oracle, my query is

```
insert all
 into table_a values(id, name)
 into table_a_a values(id, name)
select SYS_GUID() AS id, name from table_source
```

'id' field is both unique key in table_a, and unique and foreign key in table_a_a.
Using select SYS_GUID(), I'm trying to insert the row with same guid in both tables.
The guids are created each time when rows are inserted into each table.
The select query get more than one rows.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: you need to take guid() in a variable first then insert. You can not insert in the way you mentioned above. insert into..select.... then again insert into...select...

Comment: But this way, the rows with the same guid are inserted into table_a. So constraints issue occurs..